# Proper way of using allEvents()

Tags: web3js, events, logs

I'm trying to get all events for a contract:

```
let events = token.allEvents({fromBlock: creationBlock, toBlock: 'latest'}, (err, res) => {
    try {
        let result = events.get();
        console.log(result);            
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);            
    }
});
```

For some reason, the callback code is called every time an event is found. I could live with that, but if there are no events, the callback is never called. I'm trying to list all events for a contract (not interested in watching for events).

When I try to use it synchronously, `events.get()` throws an error saying synchronous methods are not supported.

Comment: "For some reason, the callback code is called every time an event is found." That's the expected behavior. I'm a bit confused about what you're trying to do. Could you explain? Maybe give an example?

Comment: @smarx I need to get all events emitted by my contract.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I shouldn't have used the callback in this case. Here's the working code:

```
let events = token.allEvents({fromBlock: creationBlock, toBlock: 'latest'});
events.get((error, events) => {
    if (error)
        console.log('Error getting events: ' + error);
    else
        return res.json(events);
});
```

Comment: I believe this is just a longer way of writing the code that uses a callback. (The callback already gets invoked for each event that occurs. I think the issue is that you were then calling `get` again instead of just logging the event.)

Comment: I'm writing a backend handler that needs to return all past events to the client. So, waiting until an event happens is not an option for me. Using a callback for `allEvents` would be handy for a frontend code that displays events in real time.

Comment: Oh, sorry, just realized you're doing `get` instead of `watch`. The callback supplied to `allEvents` is equivalent to `watch`.

Comment: OK, good to know. I couldn't find anything in the docs explaining this.